# Remove Double quotes from text when exporting csv file via PhpExcel and open it with notepad

Tags: php, csv

I am exporting the csv file using PhpExcel but when I open it with notepad it shows Double quotes around the text. I do not want these double quotes.
Can anyone help me?

Below is demo output from that file:

```
"Credits","Modified_User","Plain_Course_Name","Popular_Courses","ISBN_9","ISBN_7","Course_Number","ISBN_8","Book_2_REQUIRED_or_OPTIONAL","ISBN_5","ISBN_6","Course_Status","ISBN_3","ISBN_4","Book_9_REQUIRED_or_OPTIONAL","Bookstore_2_Course_Status","ISBN_2",
```

to generate csv, I am using below code:

`$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'csv');`

If I use following code then the output in notepad is correct but it will change the data order in excel csv file.

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV')->setDelimiter(',')
                                                              ->setEnclosure('"')
                                                              ->setLineEnding("\r\n")
                                                              ->setSheetIndex(0)
                                                              ->save(__DIR__.'/'.$file_name);
```

Comment: Thank you for edit and make it correct.

Comment: Also can any one help me in how to export csv in comma delimited text format in PhpExcel?

Answer (score 7):

So, from what I understand of PHPExcel, the text enclosure is set by default to use ", which is why you are having " around your text in your file. The second snippet of code hits on directly what you need though, so you were close!

You should be able to use $createWriter->setEnclosure('') in order to print your items without double quotes.

In your code that would look something like this:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV')->setDelimiter(',')
                                             ->setEnclosure(' ')
                                             ->setLineEnding("\r\n")
                                             ->save(__DIR__.'/'.$file_name);
```

I'm not sure if you need the setLineEnding, especially if it is one line. Perhaps for later parsing you might. I hope that this information helps out!

There is additional documentation on the subject on their gitHub: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/10-Reading-and-Writing.md

Comment: Thank you "crepuscularCoder" for sharing information.
But whenever I use  $objWriter->setEnclosure(' ') the text in notepad will reflects correct but when I open the file in Excel the records mismatched(breaks into different positions).

Comment: That's strange. It might be that there is some sort of formatting that is not supposed by .csv. 

So, in your text file the data looks like apple, banana, cherry, grape, etc ? 
If you remove the setLineEnding does it make a difference?

Comment: No. Actually in csv there is long text portion available so when I use ->setEnclosure(' ') that text breaks into different positions.

Comment: Hi all need yours help in phpexcel export csv file.
I export the csv file from reports available on another site the sample report text is like " Spring - Full Semester, Fall - Full Semester, Summer - Summer Semester " (without double quotes I manually add it) but when it exported it shows like [Spring - Full Semester, Fall - Full Semester, Summer - Summer Semester] with brackets around it.
Please help me around this issue.